# Using system.io.packaging.zippackage from windowsbase.dll in a server app

Tags: .net, wpf, zip

In a server application I need to be able to process a zip file. I've [system.io.packaging.zippackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx) from windowsbase.dll in client base applications before now and it seems to do the job quite nicely. I'd like use this in a server app to avoid taking a dependency on a third party package. However, using something from a WindowsBase.dll in a server app makes me slight nervous because this dll was released as part of WPF one could get the impression that this was only indented to be used in GUI apps.

So, is system.io.packaging.zippackage safe to use in a server app? Is there any reason that it was placed in WindowsBase.dll rather than a more general dll, say System.dll or similar.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480765/when-is-it-okay-to-reference-windowsbase-dll) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally safe to use on the server, particularly if all that you are trying to do is take advantage of the ZipPackage support. You should be aware that there could be thread safety issues (like two requests trying to access the same archive) but if you are doing something like zipping up some files to send to the browser you should be just fine.